# Reading eeprom on linux without root right

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-device-driver, root, buildroot

I am working on `Linux 3.14.28`, build with `buildroot` for an embeded system.

How can I read the file `/sys/devices/i2c.4/i2c-1/1-0052/eeprom` without root privilege?

Is there a solution to permanently change permission instead of changing it on each reboot of Linux with a script.

I'm not using `udev` but `static table`. I easily manage to change permission:

- using `device_table_dev.txt` for `/dev` files
- using `device_table.txt` for `/home/files`

But it has no effect on `/sys/devices/i2c.4/i2c-1/1-0052/eeprom`

Comment: its a possible duplicate of [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68897/how-to-set-permissions-in-sys-permanent)

Comment: I checked all node of the tree, and it doesn't seems to be a link. I was first working on `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0052/eeprom` which is a link, but I change for the "real" file and tree

Comment: You have to change the permissions to the host controller device, something like `/dev/i2c-1`.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, don't use static table. It really doesn't make any sense to not use devtmpfs these days, unless you're using a kernel older than 2.6.32.

Then, the device table is about changing permission of files in /dev. The permission of files in /sys is directly controlled by the kernel itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the permissions of the i2c bus device file `/dev/i2c-*`, not the eeprom file in `/sys`.
Using `udev` following rule should do the job:

```
KERNEL=="i2c-[0-9]*", GROUP="dialout"
```

Generally something similar should be also possible with `static table` as you can handle `/dev/i2c-*` like every other `/dev/*` file.